# SQL Script Gone Wrong Need Help Recovering '[' character in column names causing problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

used a script to rename a column which has caused a problem...

```
sp_RENAME 'products.isvalid' , '[_is_valid_system]', 'COLUMN'
```

Now I have a column name with square brackets in, and I can't access the column to resolve the problem.

Column Name:

```
[_is_valid_system]
```

An attempt to repair the issue like so fails because of the special characters in the command:

```
sp_RENAME 'products.[_is_valid_system]' , '_is_valid_system', 'COLUMN'
```

Any way of escaping these characters?

Even if I can just select from the column that will be good enough, but the following obviously does not work because of the special meaning of squared brackets in SQL server.

```
select [is_valid_system] from products
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`sp_RENAME 'products."[_is_valid_system]"' , '_is_valid_system', 'COLUMN'`

Comment: Thanks man, your a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

If [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393%28SQL.90%29.aspx) is ON (should be default), try this

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'products."[_is_valid_system]"' , '_is_valid_system', 'COLUMN'
```

FYI, you can use this too to query

```
SELECT "[is_valid_system]" FROM products
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember the quotes thing!